# Inequality involving Quantity stays unevaluated

Tags: bugs, units, inequalities

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and solved in 11.1**

---

An expression like this one

```
a < x < b
```

is represented as

```
Less[a, x, b]
```

while an expression like

```
a < x <= b
```

is represented as

```
Inequality[a, Less, x, LessEqual, b]
```

On my machine a problem arise when an `Inequality` expression contains `Quantity` expressions. For example

```
Quantity[6368, "Kilometers"] < Quantity[5500, "Kilometers"] <= 
 Quantity[6371, "Kilometers"]
```

stays unevaluated:

> Quantity[6368, "Kilometers"] < Quantity[5500, "Kilometers"] <= 
>    Quantity[6371, "Kilometers"]

An annoying workaround is to `LogicalExpand` all `Inequality` expressions that may contains `Quantity` expression.

```
LogicalExpand@%
```

> False

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Better send this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: `Simplify` also works.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I checked and this is a known (internally reported) issue. This example will be added to the report.

Comment: @chuy Not if the inequality is undecidable.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is there anything built-in that makes it easy to bring inequalities to a canonical form?  There seem to be several different ways to represent the same inequality.  `LogicalExpand`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm afraid I do not know a definitive answer to this. My guess is `LogicalExpand` will be reasonably close, depending on what exactly is wanted. If equivalent sets of inequalities need to be put into the same unique form, then that will not do the job. But I believe it will do a reasonable job of putting them into conjunctions of simple inequalities.