# Strange behavior with Inequality and pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, inequalities

An expression like this one

```
a < x < b
```

is **normally** represented as

```
Less[a, x, b]
```

while an expression like

```
a < x <= b
```

is represented as

```
Inequality[a, Less, x, LessEqual, b]
```

(1) What is the reason of the following strange behavior of pattern matching and `Inequality` expressions?

```
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], _Inequality]
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], Inequality[___]]
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
 Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2]]
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
 Inequality[_, Less, _, LessEqual, _]]
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
 Inequality[1, _, x, LessEqual, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> False
> True
> True
> False
> ```

(2) How to do pattern matching properly with `Inequality`?

(3) Elegant way to convert all the `Inequality` in an expression to their normal form when possible (because of [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81357/inequality-involving-quantity-stays-unevaluated))?

Comment: As for the first and second `Inequality[___]` evaluates to `True` immediately. Try `HoldPattern[Inequality[___]]` instead: that one then works. I think the issue is *always*  pre-evaluation of the pattern. Look at what `Inequality[1, _, x, LessEqual, 2]` evaluates to.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22948/why-is-replaceall-behaving-like-this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is pre-evaluation of the pattern. For the ones that evaluate to `False`:

```
Inequality[___]
(* True *)
```

and

```
Inequality[1, _, x, LessEqual, 2]
(* Inequality[1, _, x] && x <= 2 *)
```

Neither of those evaluated forms will match

```
Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2]
```

To fix this, merely add `HoldPattern`. For instance,

```
MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], HoldPattern[Inequality[___]]]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

`Inactivate` is helpful in analyzing this problem.

```
Inactivate[
  Column[
    {MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], _Inequality],
     MatchQ[Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], Inequality[___]],
     MatchQ[
       Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
       Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2]],
     MatchQ[
       Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
       Inequality[_, Less, _, LessEqual, _]],
     MatchQ[
       Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
       Inequality[1, _, x, LessEqual, 2]]}],
 MatchQ]
```

[image: result]

The above results show clearly why the second and last forms evaluate to `False`. They also suggests a work-around.

```
Inactivate[
  MatchQ[
    Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
    Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2]], 
  Inequality]
```

> `True`

```
Inactivate[
  MatchQ[
    Inequality[1, Less, x, LessEqual, 2], 
    Inequality[1, Less, _, LessEqual, 2]], 
  Inequality]
```

> `True`